# Error when installing Scribes text editor in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: python, text, editor

When running ./configure script, there is an error:

*Error: Python bindings for gtkspell was not found.*

Looking for this package, I discovered that python-gtkspell has been renamed to python-gtkspellcheck. Is it possible to edit the configure script, so that it can recognize the existence of gtkspell with the new name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Easy way

Simple hacky way is to install Scribes 0.4 build 910 from Ubuntu 14.04 LTS repository:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/python-support/python-support_1.0.15_all.deb
sudo apt install ./python-support_1.0.15_all.deb

wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/gnome-python-extras/python-gtkspell_2.25.3-13_amd64.deb
sudo apt install ./python-gtkspell_2.25.3-13_amd64.deb

wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/s/scribes/scribes_0.4~r910-0ubuntu2_all.deb
sudo apt install ./scribes_0.4~r910-0ubuntu2_all.deb
```

and then use it:

> [image: Scribes 0.4 on Ubuntu MATE 18.04 LTS]

Note: this version is not too old as official site has [build 954](http://scribes.sourceforge.net/download.html).

---

## Harder way

Download and install two deb-packages as written above:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/python-support/python-support_1.0.15_all.deb
sudo apt install ./python-support_1.0.15_all.deb

wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/gnome-python-extras/python-gtkspell_2.25.3-13_amd64.deb
sudo apt install ./python-gtkspell_2.25.3-13_amd64.deb
```

Then install development packages:

```
sudo apt install build-essential intltool gnome-doc-utils \
pkg-config bzr python-gtksourceview2 rarian-compat python-glade2
```

Then download source code from [Bazaar repository](https://code.launchpad.net/~mystilleef/scribes/scribes-dev-0.4), compile and install the application:

```
bzr branch lp:scribes 
cd scribes
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

and use it:

> [image: The freshest Scribes 1052]